# How to update ListBox from TextChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a TextBox which I let the user enter some text which then filters a ListBox (somewhat like autocomplete). However, I'm not sure how to update the ListBox once the TextChanged event is fired on the TextBox?

**View**

```
<TextBox Name="textBox" TextChanged="textBox_TextChanged"/>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding NamesList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public ObservableCollection<string> NamesList
{
    get
    {
        IEnumerable<string> names = MethodCallToGetStrings();
        return new ObservableCollection<string>(names);
    }
}

public void UpdateNamesList(string _searchTerm)
{
    IEnumerable<string> names = MethodCallToGetStrings()
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(_searchTerm))
        .Select(x => x.Name);

    // how to update NamesList from here?
}
```

**TextBox Event**

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    m_viewModel.UpdateNamesList(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Can't assign names to NamesList due to different types, also tried creating a new ObservableCollection.

Comment: Why are you creating a new ObservableCollection each time you get NamesList? Also, where is your setter?

Comment: @RodrigoSilva Yep, that was probably where I was going wrong. `public ObservableCollection<string> NamesList { get; set; }` now works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void UpdateNamesList(string _searchTerm)
{
    IEnumerable<string> names = MethodCallToGetStrings()
        .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(_searchTerm))
        .Select(x => x.Name);

    NamesList.Clear();
    foreach(name in names) 
    {
       NamesList.Add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to select full x not it's property than how we will right the code.